# Is an image of a function f for Dom(f) always equal to Rg(f)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let's look at the definition of an image of some function $f: A\rightarrow B$.

An image of a function $f$ for some subset $X\subseteq A$ is $\{b\in B \text{ | }f(x)=b \text{ for some } x \in X\}$.

Does that mean that an image of $f$ for set $A$ is $Rg(f)$ if  $Rg(f)$ = $\{ y\in B \text{ | } \exists x\in A.f(x)=y\}$?

In other words - is an image of $f$ for a set that is its domain is a set that is its range?

Comment: Yes same thing..

Comment: Except for different letters, the two sets defined have the same definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: $f[X] = \{b \in B: f(x) = b \text{ for some } x \in X\}$, and then $\operatorname{Rg}(f) = f[A]$, where $A$ is the domain of $f$.